# Cylinder in topology

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, geometry

$X$ is any given set.

$I$ is interval $[0,1]$ .

$X\times I$ is called cylinder with base $X$.

$X \times$ {$0$} and $X \times $ {$1$} are called lower and upper bases.

[image]

Can you explain why is there small cylinder ,maybe there is some meaning to it? And what lecturer wants to show with marking outside of that small cylinder?

Comment: I think it's just meant to indicate that the set $X$ has a "hole" in it in this particular case, and so the cylinder derived from $X$ has a "hole" in it as well.

Comment: Yeah, the picture is meant to indicate that the topological kind of “cylinder” is different from a standard geometric cylinder. So, while there are two geometric cylinders in the picture, there is only one topological cylinder.